# Troubleshooting Salesforce REST API errors

Tags: php, rest, salesforce

I am working on a Laravel project that interacts with Salesforce. The app mainly creates user accounts, cases and updates an existing case with data collected from the users. During certain API calls, I am getting  HTTP status code 400 and the response phrase simply says 'Bad Request'. I understand that a 'Bad Request' error happens when Salesforce fails to parse the data send via REST API. My question is, is there any way to debug these errors in a better way? Is there any by which I can get the exact field in the data sent to Salesforce which is causing the error?

Comment: The response body usually has some details on the error.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It simply says 'Bad Request'.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the response body?  That is just the HTTP status.

Comment: Are you sending any authorization headers on the request?, like session id or Oauth?